# Protection banner shouldn’t override bounty banner in the app

Tags: feature-request, bounties, ios-app, protected-questions, information-display

In the app, a question that has an open bounty has a banner at the bottom indicating that there is a bounty:

[image: Screenshot of a question with the bounty banner]

However, if the question is also protected then the banner at the bottom is about the protection and there is no indication of the bounty:

[image: Screenshot showing a bountied question displaying the protected banner]

On the actual site, both banners are displayed:

[image: Screenshot showing the question on the site where both banners are displayed]

This means that when you are in the question on the app you have no way of knowing that the question has a bounty. And even if you saw the bounty on the question list, there is no display telling you who offered it and how long it will be for. On a regular bountied question that information does display when you click on the banner:

[image: Screenshot showing bountied question with the additional information]

Granted you can retrieve this information from the revision history of the question, however:

- You have to know that there is a bounty in the first place to do this.
- You have to know that you can find bounty information in the revision history.
- If the question has never been edited you can’t access the revision history on the app.

Therefore, is it possible to change the way the question displays, so that even if the question is protected the bounty information will still be there?